# Predictions are returning strange values

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to make a prediction, but the values of the output are very strange and out of the ordinary, I used the same model in another application made in android studio and in another format ('pb' 'txt)' and it was working, I converted to stay compatible with React Native and the output values do not match what I expected.
**Values exceed 100%**

```
const loadMobileNetModel = async () => {
  const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(bundleResourceIO(modelJson, modelWeights));
  setModelFound(true);
  return model;
  }

const getPrediction = async(tensor) => {
 const results = await mobilenetModel.predict(tensor).dataSync()[0];
 console.log(results);
}

const handleCameraStream = (imageAsTensors) => {
const loop = async () => {

  if(modelFound){
    const verbose = true;
    const nextImageTensor = await imageAsTensors.next().value;
    const floatImageTensor = tf.cast(nextImageTensor, 'float32');
    const ReshapeImageTensor = floatImageTensor.reshape([1, 416, 416, 3]);
    await getPrediction(ReshapeImageTensor);
  }
```

Outputs:
19.368160247802734
22.82789421081543
18.992399215698242
36.17805099487305
30.855012893676758
97.73448944091797
-1205.3101806640625
-126.22428894042969
148.76333618164062
...

Comment: What is your output for we can compare them?

Comment: Include the output of results. Also model.predict is an async function so you would need to await the prediction.

Comment: updated with the program outputs

Comment: The outputs might be unscaled logits. You can try applying a softmax function to get predictions.

Comment: does this method work in tensorflow.js to react native?
I still don't know how this metdo works and how to use it